# cannot use Indy in lazarus

Tags: lazarus

I am install Indy from Online package manager, but cannot use indy component like `IdTCPClient` in my project, it will alert error:

```
Fatal: Can't find unit IdTCPClient used by Unit1
```

my source code:

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, IdTCPClient;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private

  public

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

end.
```

and the package screenshot (means installed Indy proper):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project, go to Project->Project Inspector, then right click "requires Packages" and add indylaz